# Running Kobuki on the Ignition Gazebo Garden and ROS 2 Humble

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot

I am new to Gazebo. I could not find anything that can run Kobuki using the Ignition Gazebo, even though some can run Kobuki using the Gazebo. For example, we are trying to reproduce [this site](https://github.com/AI-Robot-Book/turtlebot2_airobotbook) with the Ignition Gazebo. I am using ROS 2 Humble and Ignition Gazebo Garden for this project. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The following links could be useful: [1](https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros/issues/43), [2](https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros/pull/20), [3](https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros/pull/35), [4](https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros/pull/44), and [5](https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros/pull/47).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
For example, to run turtlebot2/Kobuki
<https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot4_simulator/tree/humble>
Do you know of any other ignition gazebo simulators that can run Kobuki, for example, turtlebot2/Kobuki? Also, is there any more simulator for Kobuki on the IGNition gazebo?

I don't seem to find any information on simulators on the site you gave me.
I would be very grateful if anyone could reply.